# Best practice or good strategy to write user defined exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I want to write custom Exception Class for my project. I need to create a Exception frame work so that it can be used across different project. Please guide me what all strategy or steps I need to address.

Answer (score 6):

Exceptions in Java are normal objects that inherit from Throwable. Decide if you want your exception to be checked (that is, compiler verifies `throws` clause in method signatures that can throw them), or not. If you want your custom exceptions to be checked, inherit from Exception, if not, from RuntimeException. You can also extend `Error` for unrecoverable exceptions that should cause your application to exit.

When writing your own exceptions, concentrate on making them descriptive - that is, if your exception is thrown, you should have a general idea what went wrong just looking at exception message and its stack trace. Exception constructors taking message as a parameter are your friend there. Both `Exception` and `RuntimeException` provide necessary constructors, so your constructors in simplest case will just have to call them.

Remember to keep your exceptions at the same level of abstraction as methods throwing them. If, for example, you have a general interface for accessing domain objects that hides implementation details of particular database, in case of errors you shouldn't simply rethrow exceptions thrown by the database connection. You can wrap those exceptions in your own exception class, with the right level of abstraction. As before, `Exception` and `RuntimeException` already have constuctors for that.

Can't really help you with planning exception hierarchy in your project and particular classes, as you didn't provide any details about it. Please update your question with more specific description of your projects.

Comment: Actually I am trying to build a component where all possible features will be available. I am not finding any list of approach(do's and don'ts)  which I Should take care while making a custom exception.I have used internationalisation in my Exception class ; That only; Should it be good practice  of overridding printStackTrace()

Comment: I wouldn't recommend overriding printStackTrace(), as often it's the only thing developer has to help him catch a bug and the data there is quite crucial. How would you change it?